# concatenate arbitrary long list of matches in SQL subquery

Tags: sql, firebird

imagine 2 tables (rather stupid example, but for the sake of simplicity, here you go)

```
words
  word_id

letters
  letter
  word_id
```

how can i select all words while selecting all letters that belong to a word and concatenating them to said word? it is important that the letters are returned in the order they appear in the table, as the letter may be mixed into other words, but the order is correct.

```
|word_id|    |word_id|letter|
+-------+    +-------+------+
|      1|    |      1|     H|
|      2|    |      2|     B|
             |      2|     Y|
             |      1|     I|
             |      2|     E|
```

should return

```
|word_id|word|
+-------+----+
|      1|  HI|
|      2| BYE|
```

any way to accomplish this in pure SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT word_id, group_concat (letter,'') FROM letters GROUP BY  word_id;`

Comment: Firebird doesn't have `group_concat`, it has [`list`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-aggrfunc-list.html) instead (which is similar to `group_concat`)

Comment: those quotation marks have to be single `'`, else it will throw an error like `unknown column`, which makes no sense

Comment: Thanks, will update the answer. MySQL doesn't care about that.